# strict mode using assert module in nodejs

Tags: assert, strict

Could you please help me in understanding the below error:

**`js content:`**

```
const assert = require('assert').strict;
var res = assert.deepEqual([[[1, 2, 3]], 4, 5], [[[1, 2, '3']], 4, 5]);
```

**`Error:`**

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'deepEqual' of undefined

**`My understanding:`**

According to the `Nodejs` doc, using `.strict` while loading '`assert`' module will let us in restrictive mode which results in the behavior of `assert.deepEqual()` and `assert.deepStrictEqual()` to be same and as a result of this description. The output should be

> "errors.AssertionError"

please guide me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are using node v. 9.10.1 [v. 9.10.1 assert API](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert) since `strict` functionality is not compatible with previous node versions. Here is node v. 8.11.1 and [v. 8.11.1 assert API](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v8.x/api/assert.html) so as you can see `strict` is not available.

In my case it works fine using node v. 9.10.1.

```
const assert = require('assert').strict;

// check your node version
console.log(process.version)
assert.deepEqual([[[1, 2, 3]], 4, 5], [[[1, 2, '3']], 4, 5]);


v9.10.1
assert.js:49
  throw new AssertionError(obj);
  ^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Input A expected to deepStrictEqual input B:
+ expected - actual ... Lines skipped

  [
    [
...
        2,
-       3
+       '3'
      ]
...
    5
  ]
```

Comment: Thank you Alex, It is working now. after updating node from v8.9.4 to v9.10.1

Comment: It looks like the `strict` module goes back to **v9.9.0**, so the **package.json** entry would be: `"engines": { "node": ">=9.9.0" }`, see: 
https://nodejs.org/docs/v9.9.0/api/assert.html#assert_strict_mode